# similar to (applying) group isomorphism theorems

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a topological group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $K$ is a compact subset of $G$, 
if $G=HK$, then $G/H$ is compact?

Is this right?

I said this conclusion is similar to group isomorphism theorems, that is, if $K$ is a group, then  $(HK)/H$ "is" $ K/(H\cap K)$, so $(HK)/H$ is compact if $K$ is compact.

I hope it is a simple question.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Obviously, $H$ is considered a normal subgroup (but it is not stated).

Comment: So what does $\cdot /H$ mean?

Comment: @Crostul: It means taking the quotient of $G$ under the right action of the subgroup $H$ by multiplication, then equipping it with the quotient topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume $G = KH$, the function 
\begin{align*}
K &\rightarrow G/H \\
k &\mapsto kH
\end{align*}
is continuous, and surjective because $G = KH$. Hence as $K$ is compact, so is its image $G/H$. I am not sure when you change the order of $H$ and $K$, yet still insist to use left cosets.